# Spring JPA and remove entries from @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

As touched on in the following:

- [Cascade on delete using unidirectional Many-To-Many mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980177)
- [How to remove entity with ManyToMany relationship in JPA (and corresponding join table rows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095)
- [JPA JPQL: select items when attribute of item (list/set) contains another item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339889)

when removing entries from `@ManyToMany` mappings, there is an element of manual tweaking involved to remove the foreign keys.

I have been using my own JPA CRUD for years and have a nice solution for this: [CrudDao](https://github.com/fommil/common-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fommil/jpa/CrudDao.java#L409) e.g. [NoteDao](https://github.com/fommil/zibaldone/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/me/fommil/zibaldone/persistence/NoteDao.java#L61).

But I've been recently very impressed by [Spring JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) and the ability to autogenerate Cruds by declaring an interface and then creating similarly named `namedQuery`s on the `@Entity`.

But how do I fix the `@ManyToMany` remove problem? I'll essentially have `remove` methods on my Crud that expose this "feature" of JPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appear to have solved this using `@PreRemove`, as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911910/1041691

e.g. 
https://github.com/fommil/zibaldone/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fommil/zibaldone/Note.java#L74